# how to block a signal before shared library creates a thread?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I am dealing with application that requires certain signal to be blocked in every thread. Said app also dynamically links a library (libcpprest.so) which creates a thread pool during initialization. Naturally, because main executable had no chance to execute any code these threads have that signal unblocked -- which leads to mysterious crashes.

Is it possible to block a signal before dynamically linked library has a chance to create a thread?

Unacceptable solutions (that I am aware of):

- link library statically and use `init_priority` to ensure signal is blocked asap
- use "starter" utility that blocks signal and starts executable (which will inherit signals mask)

Comment: Does `libcpprest.so` create the thread pool from a constructor? If not, presumably, you have to manually call (e.g.) `init_libcpprest` from the app to create the thread pool and the app can disable the signals before this call? In other words, can you modify the app?

Comment: @CraigEstey app is under my full control, library creates threads during static variables initialization (as I observe in debugger) -- before app has a chance to run anything (I know of)

Comment: Have you tried using `static void initsigmask(void) __attribute__((constructor (101)); static void initsigmask(void) { sigset_t  mask; sigemptyset(&mask); sigaddset(&mask, SIGNUM); sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL); }` in the same compilation unit as your `main()`? In Linux, it should be run before the constructors in dynamic libraries, and do what you need it to do.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I didn't know `constructor` attribute can have a priority. I'll give it a try and report. Thank you

Comment: @NominalAnimal why does it have to be in the same TU as `main()`?

Comment: @C.M.: `initsigmask()` does not *have to* be in the same translation unit; as long as it is statically linked to the final binary, it should work. I phrased my comment the way I did, so that it would be clear that there is no need to link any library statically. As long as `initsigmask()` is in the same binary as `main()`, and has a suitable priority, it should execute before the constructors in any dynamically loaded C libraries.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Nope, it doesn't work... :-/ `initsigmask` is invoked after shared lib creates it's global variables

Comment: @C.M.: Ouch; I didn't realize the library is a C++ one; the constructor priority only works for C libraries. One option would be to not link the library directly, but dynamically load it in `main()`, after setting the signal mask, by calling `if (!dlopen("libcpprest.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL)) /* failed, see dlerror() */`.

Comment: The simplest, but most hacky solution, would be for you to examine the signal mask at the beginning of `main()`. If the signal is unblocked, block it, then re-execute self (`execvp("/proc/self/exe", argv); _Exit(127);`). This achieves the same as a starter utility (and will work cleanly with one). Very hacky, though, but that's the best you can do, I suppose, considering the authors of the library.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Loading lib dynamically won't work -- I can't compile binary (unresolved references) and handling bunch of exported symbols manually (via dlsym) is simply too impractical (esp with C++ libs). Or maybe I am missing smth here. Restarting self is actually a very neat idea... I wonder what is the catch? What are the side effects? For example, who is going to be my parent process?

Comment: @C.M.: The parent does not change, as the process simply replaces itself with itself. Even the PID stays the same. The downside is increased load time, basically. It is considered a hack because using a loader is the preferred solution. If you look at typical Linux applications, they tend to have a loader, although it usually is a script. Do put a prominent comment in your code, though, explaining both the purpose and the reason to do it this way. If you do check the signal mask, and re-execute self only if necessary, perhaps setting an environment variable too to avoid an exec loop [...]

Comment: [...] just in case the signal mask does not "take" on some system, and do have a comment in the source and documentation as to why, then I personally would accept it as a solution, and not consider it *too* hacky. (And I'm pretty anal about what I run on my system, typically running e.g. Java binaries under dedicated user accounts, using a reverse proxy in between if necessary.) Do you want an "answer" showing an example, or will you supply an answer yourself when you have it working? I think it would be useful to others too, you see.

Comment: @NominalAnimal "using a loader is the preferred solution" -- I tried to go this route, but discovered that you can't change sigmask from bash script %-) . All this trickery is getting out of hands -- I'll try to rewrite original logic that needs signals to be blocked... Instead of polling for them via `sigwaitinfo()` is dedicated thread, I'll install handlers and communicate with dedicated thread somehow. It seem to be strategically better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be possible -- shared library should block all signals in created threads if it really needs to create a thread so early.